# Как сделать так, чтобы придерживаться принципа ООП

Tags: ооп, java

Тривиальный вопрос по ООП

Может кому-то покажется очевидным, но я вот не знаю как сделать так, чтобы придерживаться принципа ООП.
Если есть класс А который инкапсулирует класс B который в свою очередь инкапсулирует класс С. И вот вдруг кому-то захотелось задать значение переменной в классе C. И так хоть до конца алафавита.
как правильней поменять значение переменной в самом вложенном классе из родительского?
 что-то вроде

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Value_inC_inB = 23;
    }
}

class A {
    private B b = new B();
    public int Value_inC_inB
    {
        get { return this.b.ValueInC; }
        set { this.b.ValueInC = value; }
    }

}
class B {
    private C c = new C();
    public int ValueInC
    {
        get { return this.c.Value; }
        set { this.c.Value = value; }
    }
}
class C {
    private int value = 7;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

}
```

или же тоже самое только функциями как `Java` в стиле `setValue(int i)` и так каждый класс передает дочернему. 
Кроме этого и варианта сделать все `public` я не виду элегантного решения. Как правильней? Может паттерн есть какой на эту тему? 
спасибо

Comment: вы собственно хотите нарушить принцип инкапсуляции, но зачем?

всё зависит от контекста, если эта переменная константа по отношению ко всей иерархии  то вынести её как `public const` если она изменяется в иерархии то только в виде параметра ну а если есть целый набор таких вот переменных то можно их вынести в отдельный класс и его уже использовать как параметр

Comment: Я не хочу нарушать принципе инкапсуляции. В этом и вопрос, подразумевает ли ООП именно такой подход в изменении переменных? 
P.S переменная не константная

Comment: - Нельзя говорить об ООП, приводя в пример классы, которые называются `A`, `B` и `C`. Они не моделируют real-world объекты, а мы из-за этого не понимаем, что вы на самом деле делаете.

- Почему вам потребовалось извне менять значение в экземпляре `C`, который создан внутри `A`? Не течет ли ваша абстракция? Тот код, который вы привели в пример, [очень сильно связан.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) Как следствие этого, вы, например, не смогли придумать адекватного названия для `Value_inC_inB`.

Comment: - Вцелом — если создавать `B` умеет только `A`, а создавать `C` умеет только `B`, то замерджите логику `B` и `C` в inner-класс `A` и выдайте наружу человеческий интерфейс. Если предыдущее утверждение неверно, то, скорее всего, текущий дизайн — плохой и надо его каким-то образом разворачивать. Опять же, см. пункт про названия `A`, `B` и `C`.

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться поменять переменную во внутреннем классе `C`, ведь вы даже не должны знать/исходить из того, что внутри `A` есть `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принципы проектирования - это во-первых, не сферический конь, которому нужно обязательно поклоняться, а во-вторых, невозможно следовать принципам, при этом оставляя дизайн без изменения.

В этом случае, наличие свойства/метода в классе `A` `Value_inC_inB` нарушает инкапсуляцию, поскольку, по идее, клиенты этого класса не знаю, что у класса `A` есть закрытое поле `B`, у которого, в свою очередь, есть закрытое поле `C`.

Если нужно обеспечить изменение клиентами поля `C`, то вместо композиции, следует использовать агрегацию, и дать возможность клиенту класса `A`, передать объект `C`, и держать у себя ссылку на него. Это позволит изменять им объект `C` напрямую, не протаскивая это через свойства/методы классов `A` и `B`.

Другими словами, нужно вот что:

```
class C
{
  public int SomethingMutable {get; set;}
}

class B
{
  private readonly C _c;
  public B(C c) {_c = c;}
}

class A
{
  private readonly B _b;
  public A(C c) {_b = new B(c);}
}
```

Теперь, у клиентов класса `A` есть возможность изменить `C` самостоятельно:

```
C c = new C();
A a = new A(c);
c.SomethingMutable = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону модификатора `protected`

Comment: А чем он поможет в этом случае? Когда нет иерархии наследования?